# convert quarter-year to month-end date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have the time column, the value is `1Q1993` (QuarterYear),and I would like to get month-end-date of the quarter (which is `1993-03-31`). Please could someone help with the SQL. I need to add to a select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. As the dates are fixed and don't move

> ```
> SET @date := "1Q1993"
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@date,'Q',-1),
> CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(@date,'Q',1) 
>        WHEN 1 THEN '-03-31'
>        WHEN 2 THEN '-06-30'
>        WHEN 3 THEN '-09-30'
>        ELSE  '-12-31' END)
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@date,'Q',-1),
> CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(@date,'Q',1) 
>       WHEN 1 THEN '-03-31'
>       WHEN 2 THEN '-06-30'
>       WHEN 3 THEN '-09-30'
>       ELSE  '-12-31' END) |
> | >:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->------- |
> | 1993-03-31                                                                                                                                                                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07ae8932b8d5130f9f20630b0bc8eb29)*

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach might be a `case` expression:

```
select 
    concat(
        right(mycol, 4),
        '-'
        case left(mycol, 1)
            when '1' then '03-31'
            when '2' then '06-30'
            when '3' then '09-30'
            when '4' then '12-30'
        end
    ) as mydate
from mytable
```

This rebuilds a string in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which MySQL will happily understand as a date.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
date(concat(substring_index(qtr,'Q',-1),'-01-01')) + interval substring_index(qtr,'Q',1)*3 month - interval 1 day
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a0a4a86900d9d6537418602ae6153a66

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract the year, convert to a date and then add some months and subtract one day:

```
select (date(concat(right(col, 4), '-01-01') +
        interval (left(col, 1) * 3 + 1) month -
        interval 1 day 
       )
```